# Do i need to buy an android phone to port my iOS app to android?

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

I normally develop OpenGL ES 2D games on my iPhone and since they're enterely written in C++ (with little iphone specific objective-c) a porting for android should be quite easy to do.

My question is: do i really need an android device just to **port** and existing game? Or will the android emulator be enough for this task?

I read somewhere that with the new GPU hardware accelleration the emulator had a significant speed boost.

Comment: Anyone telling you the emulator is good for much is selling something. Just buy Nexus 7. Not too expensive, and a pretty good device at the price.

Comment: Emulators are good for broad "is this working at all" type testing, but you will find device specific bugs, especially in open gl.  Buy a used device if you need to save cash.

Comment: @user1417683 Please accept an answer if it was useful to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator will indeed help you porting your code to android. [With the new updates, it can even run openGL ES 2 code by sending it to the underlying OS drivers](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html).
The main problem is that android is rather fragmented. You'll need at least one real device to be sure that it really runs in the correct way, and it is far better to have at least a couple more.

For example, i usually use my phone, a tablet, and i have 2 friends of mine that have different phones who test my applications. It is not unusual that the application runs fine on 3 of them, but show glitches or other problems in the last one. It can be android version, driver version, driver specific bug, and so on.

In conclusion, you can just use the emulator while porting the code, but you'll eventually need a device or two to test it, [and you'll find these are not enough](http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/important-looking-for-exotic-devices-t7185.html). If you are already spending 99$ a year for your IOS application, you can probably spend 99$ to buy at least 2 used phones to use as testing. I hope your application will earn you more than that ;)
By the way, be sure to use the [latest NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), they always fix bugs with the new releases

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to buy a phone!
Emulator can do the work well!
This will not be your main issue in porting your code to Android. 
Yes, there are GPU accelerated emulators made available by Intel [see here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android)

Comment: @user1417683 if any of these answers helped you you could give back reputation, by accepting an answer (click green tick on the left) and/or upvoting an answer (click orange up arrow on the left). Good luck with your work! maurizio